# VBA Update Textbox Value based on Option Button Selection

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, radio-button

I am working on a vba excel userform and I am stuck at a point where a textbox named "Textbox6" won't update when certain conditions are in place - Like a option button selected or not.

In other words. If Optionbuttton10 is true "only" then Textbox6 displays the value in Cell D3

If "OptionButton10" is true AND "Optionbutton2" is True then I want Textbox6 to display the cell E3

This is the code I have so far and it "looks" like it should work but I am missing something.

```
Private Sub OptionButton10_Click()
Dim D3 As Variant
Dim E3 As Variant
D3 = Sheets("Systems").Range("D3").Value
E3 = Sheets("Systems").Range("E3").Value

If OptionButton10 = True And ComboBox2 = "Standard" Or ComboBox2 = "Scale-In" Then
TextBox6.Value = D3 'this works'
ElseIf OptionButton10 = True And OptionButton2 = True Then
TextBox6.Value = E3 'this doesn't work'
End If
 TextBox6.Text = Format(TextBox6.Value, "Percent")
End Sub
```

Comment: **A)** Define "doesn't work". **B)** Your `If` statement contains a combination of `and` and `or` and no parenthesis to control how VBA evaluates it - this virtually guarantees that it won't happen the way you think it will. You probably want `If A and (B or C)`, but it's probably executing as `If (A and B) or C`.

Comment: Hi FreeMan, A) Doesn't work means that when OptionButton2 is True and then I click Optionbutton10, textbox6 doesn't update with E3 cell. Instead it stays on cell D3, which is the default value if optionbutton2 is false/unchecked. B) Let me try out the parenthesis to see if that helps.

Comment: Based on your text description, maybe you want to invert the order of checking your conditions. As this code is executing, the value of `OptionButton2` is totally irrelevant if `OptionButton10` is `true` and `ComboBox2` is "Standard" or "Scale-In". It sounds like you _may_ want to check `ComboBox2` first. Either that or I'm still misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is below.

I used a nested If statement and added the "optionbutton2 = false"

```
Private Sub OptionButton10_Click()
Dim D3 As Variant
Dim E3 As Variant
D3 = Sheets("Systems").Range("D3").Value
E3 = Sheets("Systems").Range("E3").Value

If ComboBox2 = "Standard" Or ComboBox2 = "Scale-In" Then
  If OptionButton10 = True And OptionButton2 = False Then
     TextBox6.Value = D3 
  ElseIf OptionButton10 = True And OptionButton2 = True Then
     TextBox6.Value = E3 
 End If
End If
TextBox6.Text = Format(TextBox6.Value, "Percent")
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad _you_ got it worked out! I'm not sure I'd have ever guessed this variation. :) If my answer helped, clicking the "up arrow triangle" is the normal way to say "thanks". Also, since this is your solution, be sure you click the "check mark" next to the answer so that others know what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure, but based on your comments, you may want to try either this:

```
Private Sub OptionButton10_Click()
  Dim D3 As Variant
  Dim E3 As Variant
  D3 = Sheets("Systems").Range("D3").Value
  E3 = Sheets("Systems").Range("E3").Value

  If (OptionButton10 And Not (OptionButton2)) And (ComboBox2 = "Standard" Or ComboBox2 = "Scale-In") Then
    TextBox6.Value = D3                          'this works'
  ElseIf OptionButton10 = True And OptionButton2 = True Then
    TextBox6.Value = E3                          'this doesn't work'
  End If
  TextBox6.text = Format(TextBox6.Value, "Percent")
End Sub
```

or, alternatively this:

```
Private Sub OptionButton10_Click()
  Dim D3 As Variant
  Dim E3 As Variant
  D3 = Sheets("Systems").Range("D3").Value
  E3 = Sheets("Systems").Range("E3").Value

  If OptionButton10 And OptionButton2 Then
    TextBox6.Value = E3                          'this doesn't work'
  ElseIf OptionButton10 = True And (ComboBox2 = "Standard" Or ComboBox2 = "Scale-In") Then
    TextBox6.Value = D3                          'this works'
  End If
  TextBox6.text = Format(TextBox6.Value, "Percent")
End Sub
```

Additionally, I'd **strongly** recommend that you give your buttons and boxes (including text boxes) better names. Future you will greatly appreciate it when you can look at your code and read:

```
If (ProcessFoo and Not(ProcessBar)) and (Baz = "Standard" or Baz = "Scale-In")
```

<sup>*with appropriate names for your options and combobox, if you name them `Foo` and `Bar` and `Baz`, future you may well be even more confused than if you leave them with the default names...</sup>

That will be much faster for you to understand than having to go back to the form to see what the text labels for `OptionButton10` and `OptionButton2` are...

Comment: Hi FreeMan, Thanks. I actually figured it out with very simple solution, I will add it as my answer. Also I really appreciate your comments about the control names.